# Prove that $\vec{v}-\vec{w}$ and $\vec{v}+\vec{w}$ are perpendicular if and only if $\| \vec{v} \|=\|\vec{w}\|$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the vectors:

$\vec{v}=[v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n}]$

$\vec{w}=[w_{1},w_{2},...,w_{n}]$

If $\| \vec{v} \|=\|\vec{w}\|$, which is

$\|[v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n}]\|=\|[w_{1},w_{2},...,w_{n}]\|$

$\sqrt{v_{1}+v_{2}+...+v_{n}}=\sqrt{w_{1}+w_{2}+...+w_{n}}$

Then

$\vec{v}-\vec{w}=[v_{1}-w_{1}, v_{2}-w_{2},...,v_{n}-w_{n}]$

$\vec{v}+\vec{w}=[v_{1}+w_{1}, v_{2}+w_{2},...,v_{n}+w_{n}]$

The dot product between $\vec{v}-\vec{w}$ and $\vec{v}+\vec{w}$ must be

$(\vec{v}-\vec{w})\cdot(\vec{v}+\vec{w})=0$

$0=(v_{1}-w_{1})(v_{1}+w_{1})+(v_{2}-w_{2})(v_{2}+w_{2})+...+(v_{n}-w_{n})(v_{n}+w_{n})$

Is this correct? I feel is incomplete but I don't know exactly what must be clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Two vectors are orthogonal iff the dot product is null. Use the distributive property of the dot product.
$$
0=(\vec v - \vec w)\cdot(\vec v+ \vec w)=(\vec v - \vec w)\cdot\vec v + (\vec v - \vec w)\cdot\vec w= \vec v\cdot\vec v-\vec w\cdot\vec v+\vec v\cdot\vec w
-\vec w\cdot\vec w$$

can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

Nearly there, each $(v_i - w_i)(v_i + w_i)$ can be rewritten as $v_i^2 - w_i^2$ so that when you take all the terms $-w_i^2$ to the other side you have
$\sum_i w_i^2 = \sum_i v_i^2$ and then use the definition $|| w ||^2 = \sum_i w_i^2$.

Answer (score 0):

1)Assume first $$v-w\perp v+w\Rightarrow (v-w,v+w)=0\Leftrightarrow (v-w,v)+(v-w,w)=0\Leftrightarrow (v,v)-(w,v)+(v,w)-(w,w)=0\Leftrightarrow (v,v)-(w,w)=0$$ which is $\|v\|^2=\|w\|^2$

2) Now, assume $\|v\|=\|w\|$. Then $$(v-w,v+w)=(v-w,v)+(v-w,w)=(v,v)-(w,v)+(v,w)-(w,w)=0$$

Note that it is not important how the inner product is defined. The only important thing is that is is an inner product and that the norm is defined by $\|v\|=\sqrt{(v,v)}$